# Why does changing the operator in $\lim_{h\to0}$ alter the result of this function?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f(x) = |x|$.

Attempting to differentiate $f(x)$ at 0 will fail because the limit does not exist at 0 as the left and right side are unequal.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

However, my problem is about understanding why we get a different answer on the left side and the right side.

Left side :

$$\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0+}\frac{h-0}{h} = 1$$

Right Side :

$$\lim_{h\to0-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0-}\frac{-h-0}{h} = -1$$

Why does changing the operator in $\lim_{h\to0}$ change the result of these equations? More specifically, why do I have to add $-$ before $h$ on the right side?

Comment: Because they represent different limits? These are one-sided limits. Have you seen these before? See here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/OneSidedLimits.aspx

Comment: You have your left and right sides backwards.  For the left side limit, $h \lt 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the right side limit $h \gt 0,$ so $|0+h|=h$.  For the left side limit, $h \lt 0,$ so $|0+h|=-h$.  It is just the result of applying the absolute value.  I think we are prone to intuitively think variables are positive, but that is not the case for the left side limit.