# If $x+h<0$ and $h>0$, why does $|x+h|-|x|=-h$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x+h<0$ and $h>0$

Why does

$|x+h|-|x|=-h$

I think I'm having difficulties with the absolute operator. How do I get rid of it to move on? And how does knowing that $x+h<0$ change how I can solve this?

Comment: It doesn't, necessarily. For example, $|1 - 2| - |1| \neq -(-2)$.

Comment: Hi Theo, I did a mistake that was pointed out by Arnaud. I edited my question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute operator is defined as follows:

$$\left|x\right| = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
-x & \text{if } x \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

In other words, if $x$ is positive (or zero), it stays the same. If $x$ is negative, then multiply it by $-1$ to make it positive.

When $h > 0$ and $x + h < 0$ (which happens when $|x| > h$, i.e. $x$ is "more negative" than $h$ is positive), you have $|x + h| = -(x + h) = -x - h$, and so $|x + h| - |x| = (-x - h) - (-x) = -x - h + x = -h$).

Comment: $$\left|x\right| = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
-x & \text{if } x \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

Although I knew what the absolute operator did, this really helped me understand why $|x+h| = -(x+h)$

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

If $x+h<0$ then all you can say is that $|x+h|=-x-h$.

Therefore what you are saying is that if $x+h<0$ then $-x-|x|=0$, or in other words $|x|=-x$.

Equivalently, you are saying that

> if $x+h<0$ then $x<0$.

Can you see now why it is wrong?

It becomes true, however, if you add the requirement that $h>0$.

Comment: Yes I did omit that requirement of $h>0$, I will edit my question

Comment: @CedricMartens If $h>0$, can you prove that $x+h<0\implies x<0$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-on [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853917/why-does-changing-the-operator-in-lim-h-to0-alter-the-result-of-this-functi).  Please read about [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).  When $x+h \lt 0, |x+h|=-(x+h)$ directly from the definition.  With the condition $h \gt 0$ the fact that $x+h \lt 0$ guarantees that $x \lt 0$ and $|x|\gt h$.  In that case $$|x+h|-|x|=-(x+h)-(-x)=-x-h+x=-h$$

Answer (score 0):

We can get rid of some absolute since we know if it's positive/negative.

We have $-x-h-|x|=-h$ is what you're trying to prove which means

$x=-|x|.$ This simply means $x$ is not positive.

We have $|x-h|-|x|=-h\iff{x=-|x|}.$

This can be proved. Since $x+h<0$, $h>0,$ we have to have a positive plus a negative is less than $0,$ since a positive plus a nonnegative is still positive.

Therefore, we have proven that $x$ is negative, so $x=-|x|$ which proves $|x-h|-|x|=-h$ $\boxed{\text{Q.E.D.}}$